# How to derive path from object in Rails helper function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this helper function in Rails and I wonder if the `user_path` can somehow be derived from `@user` which is passed to the function as a parameter. Right now, `user_path` is hardcoded in my function which is not pretty:

```
def link_to_next(entry)
  link_to ">>", user_path(entry.next)
end
```

This is how I use the helper function:

```
<%= link_to_next(@user) %>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: <%= url_for(@user) %>

Comment: I think Michael means `url_for(entry.next)`. Much cleaner than below solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the method `ActiveModel::Naming.param_key` that is used to define the [`form_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) method in Rails 3.2.13:

```
@foo = User.new
# =>  #<User id: nil, email: nil>
ActiveModel::Naming.param_key(@foo)
# => "user"
```

Now you can define `link_to_next` like this:

```
def link_to_next(entry)
  next_entry = entry.next
  path_method = "#{ActiveModel::Naming.param_key(next_entry)}_path"
  link_to('>>', send(path_method, next_entry))
end
```

Comment: Hi, can I just ask, how did you come about this knowledge? Did you research the question or are you simply very familiar with the innards of Rails?